# What is the difference between visitors and tourists?

Tags: simcity-2013

I was under the impression that visitors comprise workers and shoppers from neighbouring cities but tourists spawn out of thin air because in my tourist city, I have ~30000 tourists but barely 300 visitors.

But when I started a new city in an isolated area with no neighbours by road, I had no shoppers or workers from neighbouring cities (because there are none). About ~1800 tourists came through my train station, at the same time, I also had about ~1800 visitors.

So the second scenario contradicts my previous belief. Has anyone figured this out?

Answer (score 1):

Tourists and Commuters are both counted as Visitors.

Comment: that doesn't make sense because he has 30k tourists and 300 visitors.

Comment: He doesn't have 30000 tourists.  He has attraction capacity for 30000 tourists.

Answer (score 0):

I confirmed that my visitors consist of commuters only (workers + shoppers). For some reason my isolated city still had around 1800 shoppers commuting in from god knows where.